# Break a series of timeout commands?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

If I have a function like so:

```
function x()
{
    animate(a, 2000);
    animate(b, 3000);
    animate(c, 4000);
}
```

Where - a, b & c - are variables representing elements on the page, and the number is a parameter passed to an animate() function that uses it as a duration value for a timeout, like so:

```
function animate(src, dur)
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        src.style.opacity = 1;
    }, dur);
}
```

Everything so far is fine, but if I want the ability to break out of the animation loop, how do I go about it? Will clearTimeout() be what I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't see an animation loop, I just see three independent timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that have been assigned a timeout, may be passed to the `clearTimeout` function, which will cease the function.  You can store these variables in an array and easily clear all timeouts by iterating this array and passing the timeout to the `clearTimeout` function.

```
var timeouts = [];

/* Save timeouts into a variable and push to an array */
function animate(src, dur)
{
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        src.style.opacity = 1;
    }, dur);
    timeouts.push(timeout);
}

/** Clear all timeouts**/
function clearTimeouts(){
   for(var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++){
     clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
   }
}

//Create timeouts
x();
//Invoke clearTimeouts
clearTimeouts();
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting bit of code, but pardon my lack of understanding here - What is timeouts.push(timeout), I don't get the 'push' part. Is that a generic method for the array object created in the first line?

Comment: @Abhishek: [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) pushes an item onto an array

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `clearTimeout()` is the right way to go:

```
function animate(src, dur)
{
    return setTimeout(function() {
        src.style.opacity = 1;
    }, dur);
}
```

And save returned identifier:

```
function x()
{
    var aId = animate(a, 2000);
    var bId = animate(b, 3000);
    var cId = animate(c, 4000);
}
```

Later you simply call `clearTimeout(aId)` or whichever you desire. BTW there is no loop in your code, `setTimeout()` executes only once, as opoosed to `setInterval()`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using timeout because these are one off animations, I don't want 'em to loop... But thanks for pointing it out in any case... :)